# show existing file path using javascript and django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, file

when a user update his info the existing data should be displayed in input fields.In my problem resume file name not displaying on the right place.
[image]

i want to display the file name in **No file chosen** place with javascript. Any way???

**The Code is tooo big so i can't copy the entire code**

*this is update resume input field*

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Resume</label>
 <span style="color:#ff0000">*</span>
 <br>
 <span id="resid"></span>
 <input  type="file" name="resume" id="resume_Id"   class="form-control" required> 
</div>
```

*in here passing the database value to update field*

```
<a href="#editCorporateTrainers" class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="modal"
   onclick="editCorporateTrainersdetails(
      name = '{{ i.Name}}',
      email = '{{ i.Email}}',
      phone = '{{ i.Phone_Number}}', 
      rate = '{{ i.Rate}}',
      skills = '{{ i.Skill.all}}',
      description = '{{ i.Description}}',
      resume = '{{ i.Resume}}',
      trainer_Id = '{{i.id}}'
      );"
      >
<i class="fa fa-edit" style='color:#8773b3'  data-toggle="tooltip"></i></a>
</td>
```

*this is the function currently calling in script tag*

```
function editCorporateTrainersdetails(name ,email, phone ,rate ,skills ,description ,resume ,trainer_Id){
            document.getElementById('name_Id').value = name;
            document.getElementById('email_Id').value = email;
            document.getElementById('phone_Id').value = phone;
            document.getElementById('rate_Id').value = rate;
            document.getElementById('skillId').value = skills;
            document.getElementById('description_Id').value = description;
            document.getElementById('trainer_Id').value = trainer_Id;
            document.getElementById('resid').innerHTML = resume;
}
```

Comment: doesn't it get displayed there once the file is chose?

Comment: when i click on edit button the existing data should display on the fields. but in my case others are showing not file field.

Comment: i want display the "media/resume" into "no file chosen" place.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: any reason??? actually idk js

Comment: The label is only set when you choose a file. Since you're not choosing a file you can't set the label